# Does updating a pointer value affect earlier assignments

Tags: c, list, pointers, dynamic

I'm having a hard time understanding something about pointers and I'm doing an exercise with pointers and dynamic lists. I'm running into a problem where a pointer points to an instance of something I don't expect it to point to, ending in an infinite loop. There is only one explanation I can give for this behavior, given the following code:

```
graph_edge_t *tmp_edge;
graph_edge_t *last_edge = NULL;

tmp_edge->next_edge_p = last_edge;              
last_edge = tmp_edge;
```

I want `tmp_edge->next_edge_p` to equal `NULL`, but I'm afraid it equals `tmp_edge` after executing this. Is this correct? Is there a way where I can give `tmp_edge->next_edge_p` the value of `last_edge`, in this case `NULL`, and then alter the value of last_edge such that `tmp_edge->next_edge_p` doesn't change?

EDIT:

Here is a simplified version of the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Structure used to hold a graph vertex information. */
typedef struct graph_vertex
{
    int identifier;
    struct graph_vertex *next_vertex_p;
    struct graph_edge *edge_list_p;
} graph_vertex_t;

/* Structure used to hold a graph edge information. */
typedef struct graph_edge
{
    struct graph_vertex *adjac_vertex_p;
    struct graph_edge *next_edge_p;
} graph_edge_t;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    graph_edge_t *tmp_edge = NULL;
    
    graph_edge_t *last_edge = NULL;
    
    int id_conn[4] = {2,3,4,5};
    
    tmp_edge = (graph_edge_t *)malloc(sizeof(graph_edge_t));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", id_conn[i]);
            
        tmp_edge->adjac_vertex_p = malloc(sizeof(graph_vertex_t));
        tmp_edge->adjac_vertex_p->identifier = id_conn[i];
        tmp_edge->next_edge_p = last_edge;  
            
        if(tmp_edge->next_edge_p != NULL)
            printf("LE: %d : TMP %d : EDGE: %d \n",
                   last_edge->adjac_vertex_p->identifier, 
                   tmp_edge->adjac_vertex_p->identifier,
                   tmp_edge->next_edge_p->adjac_vertex_p->identifier);          
        
        last_edge = tmp_edge;
        /*tmp_edge->next_edge_p points to wrong vertex*/    
    }
}
```

I want Last_edge to store the information of the edge from the previous loop, that's why I set `last_edge` to `tmp_edge` after printing, however when I print `last_edge` above that equals statement I see last_edge already equals `tmp_edge`:

Current output:

```
2 3 LE: 3 : TMP 3 : EDGE: 3 
4 LE: 4 : TMP 4 : EDGE: 4 
5 LE: 5 : TMP 5 : EDGE: 5
```

Wanted Output:

```
2 3 LE: 2 : TMP 3 : EDGE: 3 
4 LE: 3 : TMP 4 : EDGE: 4 
5 LE: 4 : TMP 5 : EDGE: 5
```

Comment: It should equal `NULL`. Can you include https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as the problem clearly seems to be somewhere else?

Comment: @domen I'll try to see if I can show a better example but it's gonna be hard as the problem occures when working with data but I think the problem's origin lies when reading the data... putting all that into an easily exectuable example might be hard

Comment: In C statements are executed sequentially. By assigning a value you just copy a value into a variable. You do not define some relationship that will last after the statement was executed. C assignments are not like formulas in an Excel-Spreadsheet

Comment: @BRHSM then you can also include a very simple input text for input data. Minimising the problematic code is not just for our convenience, it is a very useful debugging technique. After all, the simpler the example is, the less things could be a problem, and minimising it will often lead to code that doesn't show the weird behaviour anymore, so you only need to analyse what happens with a small code change.

Comment: @domen I gave it a try, hope the example works to show what's happening! The infinite loop is probably due to what's shown in the example, where because last_edge is equal to tmp_edge, the link to the next edge in the list is actually made to itself. I hope it's OK for me to update the question after the answer to the original question was given, let me know if I need to make a new question!

Comment: This makes it clear to me. Print addresses of `tmp_edge` and `last_edge` (printf %p), and you'll see what's going on. Btw, I personally think changing the question the way you did is fine, as it's obvious what the old question was, and new text just clarifies it.

Comment: I found the problem too, for some reason putting tmp_edge's malloc one line above the other malloc and therefor in the loop fixed it! You were right on the debugging thing

Comment: Your edit introduced a completely different question. That is not acceptable on SO. The content of questions shall not be changed after comments or answers were given. Also only 1 question per post is allowed. If you have another problem after your question was answered, you can create a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does updating a pointer value affect earlier assignments?

**No**

C is a procedural language. It is not like an Excel spreadsheet where content of a cell is updated if other cells change.
Each statement is executed after the previous was finished. (At least the compiler has to create code that behaves as if that was the case).
A statement (an assignment is just a statement) has no past or future. It is evaluated at a given time and whatever happens afterwards is not taken into account.

In C you do not define dependencies between variables if you write an assignment.
An assignment only copies some bits in memory from one place to another.

```c
tmp_edge->next_edge_p = last_edge;              
last_edge = tmp_edge;
```

In this code the first line creates code that copies content of `last_edge` into the memory where `tmp_edge->next_edge_p` is located.
Afterwards there is no trace of the source of the data. You can alter `last_edge` as much as you want without affecting `tmp_edge->next_edge_p`.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I'll have to look for what's causing tmp_edge->next_edge_p to point to tmp_edge somewhere else then...